# How to add context to already bounded Vue method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'd like to update JS objects by Vue dropdown components.
I have tried:
- bind the function but it was already bounded by Vue.
- add extra parameter but it is ignored by dropdown Vue component

Component: https://github.com/vue-garden/vue-dropdown/blob/master/src/Dropdown.vue

```
<tr v-for="decision in decisions" :key="decision.name">
<td>
    <dropdown :multiple="true" :data="decision.domain" :cbChanged="dropdownChange.bind(decision)"></dropdown>
    <!-- dropdown :multiple="true" :data="decision.domain" :cbChanged="dropdownChange"></dropdown -->
</td>
</tr>
...
function dropdownChange(value) {
    console.log(this); // Vue component (OK)
    console.log(this.name) // undefined (how to pass name to this method?)
    console.log(value); // new value (OK)
    // Goal: this.decisions[name] = value;
}
```

How can I update decision value? Is it impossible?